# document.getElementById(element).innerText = variable

Tags: javascript, dom, for-loop, getelementbyid, innertext

I'm trying to write a loop to improve the way I assign values to html elements on a web page.

at the moment I use....

```
document.getElementById("Season201516Score1").innerHTML = Game201516Score1;
document.getElementById("Season201516Score2").innerHTML = Game201516Score2;
document.getElementById("Season201516Score3").innerHTML = Game201516Score3;
```

and so on....

The variables are

```
var Game201516Score1= "L 0-2"
var Game201516Score2= "W 1-0"
var Game201516Score3= "D 2-2"
```

The loop i'm using is

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) 
{
element = 'Season201516Score' + i
Score = ('Game201516Score' + i)
document.getElementById(element).innerText = Score;
}
```

It works in so far that it puts text in the correct elements on the page but rather than the values "`L 0-2`", "`W 1-0`" or "`D 2-2`" it gives the text "`Game201516Score1`", "`Game201516Score2`" and "`Game201516Score3`".

Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Score = ('Game201516Score' + i)
```

is a string and not a variable. So you are assigning that string and not the variable to the html. You need to convert the string to a variable to be able to use it first.
If it's a global variable then `window[Score]` should give you the correct answer instead of only using Score. Else you can also use `this[Score]`.

Comment: for  (var i = 6; i <= 7; ++i) 
   Thanks, thought it was something simple! {
    element = 'Season201516Score' + i
    Score = ('Game201516Score' + i)
    document.getElementById(element).innerText = window[Score];
    }

Comment: @GazzaLDN yes, that should solve the problem you have, though this still is a bad practice, use arrays as suggested by Shreyas or make an object

Comment: Thanks,, window[Score] works a treat.                                                                  
document.getElementById(element).innerText = window[Score];
}

Comment: Hi saranshkataria, I have upvoted your answer and Shreyas, but as I am a Newbie with a low reputation score, it doesn't show up publically yet!

Answer (score 1):

Can you store the scores in an array? Something like this -

```
var Game201516Score = [];
Game201516Score[0]= "L 0-2"
Game201516Score[1]= "W 1-0"
Game201516Score[2]= "D 2-2"

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
{
   element = 'Season201516Score' + i
   document.getElementById(element).innerText = Game201516Score[i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shreyas, I agree arrays are the correct way to do it, but was after a quick fix and the converting the string to variable works well for my current problem.

Answer (score 0):

**eval**: Change the line `Score = ('Game201516Score' + i);` to `Score = eval('Game201516Score' + i);`.

**window**: If `eval` is not works for you, then try this for above line `Score = window["Game201516Score" + i];`;

Hope this will be fine!

Comment: Ack, `eval` - about the worst solution you could suggest!

Comment: eval should be avoided if possible

Comment: Can you 'please explain why `eval` should avoided above code snippet?

Comment: @DeepakBiswal http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Comment: eval isn't always evil. There are times where it's perfectly appropriate. Anyways I have updated my answer to use `window` method.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is put your variables somewhere explicit - by using `var` it's in current scope, which is quite possibly `window` but that could depend (for example, if this code is actually in a function)

```
window.myScores.Game201516Score1= "L 0-2"
window.myScores.Game201516Score2= "W 1-0"
window.myScores.Game201516Score3= "D 2-2"
```

Then your other bit of code would use square-bracket notation to access these variables

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) 
{
    element = 'Season201516Score' + i
    Score = window.myScores['Game201516Score' + i];
    document.getElementById(element).innerText = Score;
}
```